# MySQL counting instances of column values and sorting by column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a rather advanced query I need to do on a table that holds trouble tickets sent in by customers, to gather statistics about the tickets, and to order and sort by various counts and/or column values.

Tickets table:

```
+---------------------------+       
| product_id | issue        |
+------------|--------------+
| 1          | missing-part |
| 1          | missing-part |
| 1          | broken-part  |
| 2          | broken-part  |
| 2          | broken-part  |
| 2          | missing-part |
| 2          | missing-part |
| 2          | missing-part |
+---------------------------+
```

First, I need to count the total number of tickets per product. In this case, `product_id 1` has 3 tickets and `product_id 2` has 5 tickets. Then, I need to get the values of the `issue` column and the number of occurrences of each. So at this point, I'm expecting something like this:

```
[
  'product_id' => 1,
  'issues'     => 3
  'issue_nums' => [
    'missing-part' => 2,
    'broken-part'  => 1
  ]
],
[
  'product_id' => 2,
  'issues'     => 5,
  'issue_nums' => [
    'missing-part' => 3,
    'broken-part'  => 2
  ]
]
```

Then, I need to be able to order by the number of of occurrences of each issue, for example: `ORDER BY COUNT(missing-part)` or `COUNT(broken-part)`. In other cases, I just need to be able to order the products by number of issues in total rather than by the issue values themselves (so ordering by `COUNT(issues)`).

Thanks!

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You're looking for a crosstab query. [Example](http://evolt.org/node/26896)

Comment: @JayBlanchard added an SQL Fiddle to the question that demonstrates where the query is at so far, and edited the question to clarify what additions the query needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come pretty close with two levels of aggregation:

```
select t.product_id, sum(cnt) as total,
       group_concat(issue, ':', cnt separator ',') as issues
from (select t.product_id, t.issue, count(*) as cnt
      from tickets t
      group by t.product_id, t.issue
     ) tp
group by t.product_id;
```

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle of your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/323bbb/32. It has almost everything, except being able to order the results by issue occurrence. For example: which products have the most `missing-parts` or `broken-parts`?

Comment: I went ahead and accepted your answer and moved the second half of the question to a new question to avoid confusion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044970/mysql-order-by-occurrences-of-a-specified-value

Answer (score 1):

yu could use a subselect for count product_id occurence and a main select for issuse

```
  select t1.product_id, t2.product_count, t1.issue, count(*) count_issue
  from  Tickets t1
  inner join  (
  select product_id, count(*)  product_count
  from Tickets 
  group by product_id) t2 on t2.product_id = t1.product_id
  group by t1.product_id, t2.product_count, t1.issue
  order by  count_issue
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added an SQL Fiddle example to the question that demonstrates where it's at so far. Basically the data formatted there is exactly how it needs to be, except for the `Issues` column, which should list out the issues submitted for the product, and the number of times that issue occurs. Then, I need to also be able to sort by number of issue occurrences, so for example highest->lowest number of `missing-parts`. Does that make sense?

Comment: t1.issue and count_issue should return  then isseus submitted and the related  occurring time .. and order  by coun_issue shoudl return the list order by number of occurrence ...  ..