# MySQL order by occurrences of a specified value

Tags: mysql, sql

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/323bbb/32)

First, we're counting the total number of tickets per product, and grouping by `product_id`. Then we're getting the values of the `issue` column and the number of occurrences of each. This much is already demonstrated in the fiddle.

**What I need is to be able to order by the number of occurrences of each issue**. For example, we want to order by products with the highest number of `broken-part` or `not-received`, so it'll order by the value of the `issue` column and sort by how many times that issue is present for each product.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of conditional sum.

For example

`` SUM(CASE WHEN `issue` = 'missing-part' THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) missing_part_total ``

And then order by that.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` takes an `ORDER BY` argument:

```
SELECT d2.product_id, t.title,
       SUM(`count`) AS total_issues,
       GROUP_CONCAT(`issue`, ':', `count` ORDER BY `count` DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS issues
```

Note:  Don't use single quotes for column names.  Just use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: That sorts the list of issues, which is useful, but I'm actually trying to sort the whole products list by the number of a specific issue. For example, we need to be able to sort the list of products by which ones have the most `missing-part`s, or `broken-part`s. This is for a CRM, so they want a table of their top 10 products that have issues, and then they want to be able to sort by each specific issue.